# How to associate data with struct without increasing size in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

In a renderer, I have a `MaterialParameters` struct as a base class(/base struct). For every shader in use, a user would need to create ther own struct inheriting `MaterialParameters` with all the info they want to send to the shader. This works internally by a `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>` of the struct itself and `memcpy` to a (C++) buffer, which is being send to a (GLSL) buffer of `uint` type. The user is responsible of correctly reading out the data in the shader.

Now I want to associate shader file(s) with every of these inheriting structs. Ideally, I would force a user to set this info directly into the struct.

Since the sending of data is done by a `reinterpret_cast`, I don't want to add the shader file path(s) as a member variable. I could hard code it in the struct, but it would be uploaded to the shader which is a waste of bandwidth and VRAM.

I would have liked to enforce one(/several) static method returning the path(s), but static methods can't be virtual and as far as I know I cannot enforce the presence of a static method any other way.

Is there a "nice" way of associating the extra info with my sub-structs without adding the info to the structs themselves?

The only thing I have thought of so far is an external map, but then a user adding their own struct would have to also add an entry to that map. Having it within the struct somehow would be less error prone, I believe.

Comment: Hold a (smart)pointer to the data or just store it in a `std::vector` which dynamically allocates memory itself.

Comment: Having a smart pointer to the data would mean I have a wrapper struct and a data struct, so the user would have to write two structs, right? That seems a bit inconvenient. On the other hand, an std::vector would mean every user has to implement the conversion to a uint32_t buffer themselves, since knowledge of the parameters used is required. That defeats the purpose of the simple data struct, which is to make it easy for users to add their own materials. I might consider the pointer route, but it doesn't seem to be what I was going for. Either way, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to try to read through a `reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>`'ed pointer. If you want the object representation, use `unsigned char *`

Comment: @Caleth I see. I had used `uint8_t` before, but GLSL does not support byte sized types and I wanted to use the same on both sides for offset calculation reasons. Should still be possible though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need `MaterialParameters` to be a base class. I would make it a template, with a type parameter for the user-defined data.

```
template <typename T>
struct MaterialParameters {
    T data;
    std::string shader_file;
    /// ... other data members as you need
    void write_to_glsl(unsigned char * buffer) {
        memcpy(buffer, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&data), sizeof(T));
    }
};
```

If you need it to be used polymorphically, you can still have a base:

```
struct MaterialParametersBase {
    std::string shader_file;
    /// ... other data members as you need
    virtual void write_to_glsl(unsigned char * buffer)  = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct MaterialParameters : MaterialParametersBase {
    T data;
    void write_to_glsl(unsigned char * buffer) override {
        memcpy(buffer, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&data), sizeof(T));
    }
};
```

Comment: Because I don't have a single `T data`, but arbitrary data members, e.g. `glm::vec3 albedo, float roughness, uint32_t textureSamplerOffset` in one material but `glm::vec4 hardCodedColor` in a different material.

Comment: @Tare `T` is a type parameter. Each use case will define a struct, e.g. `struct Material1 { glm::vec3 albedo; float roughness; uint32_t textureSamplerOffset; };`, and then you will use `MaterialParameters<Material1>`